# How to use JQuery function parameter to evaluate an object fields in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I appreciate your help.
I have a function in a partial _article.html.erb . It has a function inside script tag. The function has a parameter data. The data will be an id of an Article object. With this id, I want to get the name and description of the Article. How do I use this data parameter to evaluate the other fields of the Article object? And, please pardon the layout of my question and the sample code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8000');
    socket.on('news', function (data) {
        $('#test').html(
            '<table><tr><td>' + data + 
            '</td><td><a href="/articles/' + data +
            '">Show</td><td><a href="/articles/' + data + 
            '/edit">Edit</td><tr></table>'
        );
    });
</script>
```

Update: Article as defined in the rails db migration:

```
 class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
      create_table :articles do |t|
         t.string :name
         t.text :desc

         t.timestamps
      end
    end
  end
```

In the model:

```
  class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :desc, :name
  end
```

Comment: nobody has a crystal ball to know what this `Article` object looks like

Comment: OK...I thought you were wanting to handle the object parsing in javascript

Comment: Well not object parsing, but want to use the id to fetch other information from the database. The data parameter gives me an id of an object. But, I cannot use data in the erb tag, for instance  <%= Article.get_article(data) %>  where get_article is a class method that takes id as parameter. It gives me an "undefined local variable" error.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. What happens when you log `data` to console?

Comment: It gives me an the value of an id column of an article passed through data parameter.

Comment: ok..my bad you said data was an ID. Then where does Article get printed to variable in page and what is the variable name for it? Is that what `socket` is?

Comment: With this test code, I was trying to get a real time update from the sql server database and show it in the browser. For this i use trigger, and it sends id of a new or updated article to REDIS, and the REDIS publishes the id to the subcriber, which is my application.html.erb. Rather than sending everthing, I thought sending an id would be light and easy.

Comment: Right now the data is used with JQuery function to show the id of an Article, which is shown in my code above. $('#test').html(...data...data);  And about the socket, it is only the client part of the socket.

Comment: I'm not seeing how Article object is getting into JS variable, or maybe that is what you are trying to figure out

Comment: Yes. Rails has template that supports js and ruby. I was looking into that too, but no help so far.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. However, I called the jquery get() method to call the show.html.erb, the controller action of which takes the id as a parameter and gets the object. Now, I use that object in the show.html.erb to get other fields.

in _article.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8000');
 socket.on('news', function (data) {
    var url = '/articles/' + data
    $.get(url, function(x) {

            $('#test').append(x);
        });
});

</script>

<div id="test"></div>
```

I believe this can be done using partials and this is what I am going to work on now. But, at least I could see the real time update in my first test though.